# PowerShell to read or parse a numberset within a filename

Tags: powershell

I'm using PowerShell to check that certain files are present in a folder location.  If they are all present then the script will just state that 0 files are missing and if there are missing files it will tell you which ones are missing.

The files that I'm checking have a date at the end of the filename. I need my script to ignore that part of the filename or read the date part and so long as the rest of the filename is present return no errors.

Filename example: `0106-pos-20170917123002.data`

The bit of the filename I'm really interested in is `0106-pos-.data`.

Here is my script:

```
$storenum = Read-Host -Prompt "Store number (include leading zero)"
#$mbo_ip = Read-Host -Prompt "Back office IP"
$missing = 0

$sdc_pump = "\\10.xxx.xxx.xxx\gkretail\sdc\stores\device-pump"
$pos_data_file = $storenum + "-pos-"
$sdc_path = $sdc_pump + "\" + $pos_data_file

"--"
"Device Pump: config\parameter files"
if (-not $(Test-Path $sdc_path\.data)) {
    $missing++; "$sdc_path\.data not present"
}

"=="
"Store $storenum is missing $missing entries"
"=="

if (0) {
}
```

Comment: Under which conditions *exactly* are "all present" or "some (all?) missing"? Please elaborate.

Comment: Hi,I'm not sure what you're asking me here but when you run it, the script will return the below result.

Comment: 'Store number (include leading zero): 0106
--
Device Pump: config\parameter files
\\10.xxx.xxx.xxx\gkretail\sdc\stores\device-pump\0106-pos-[1-14]*.data\.data not present
==
Store 0106 is missing 1 entries
=='

Comment: the reason it states that the file is missing is because I cannot get it to read the date  on the end of the filename.......obviously the dates will always be different.

Comment: What constitutes the condition "all files (for a given store) present"? You cannot determine what's missing when you can't define what's supposed to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another person called Curtis (from Powershell forum) helped me get this script working so I'm sharing it here.

I was trying to get the wild card option working but just couldn't get it right but Curtis managed it.

```
$storenum = Read-Host -Prompt "Store number (include leading zero)"
$missing = 0

$sdc_pump = "\\10.xxx.xxx.xxx\gkretail\sdc\stores\device-pump"
$pos_data_file = $storenum + "-pos-"
$sdc_path = $sdc_pump + "\" + $pos_data_file

"--"
"Device Pump: config\parameter files"
if (-not (Get-ChildItem "$sdc_path*.data")) {
$missing++
"$sdc_path.data not present"
}

"=="
"Store $storenum is missing $missing entries"
"=="
```

This script now works fine.
I still want to thank you guys for any help and time you spent on my issue.